# Show/Hide button if iframe "src" contains certain text

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to display a button if the src attribute of an iframe on the same page contains a certain text.

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkh82p69/) for example.

I am basically trying to only show the "download MP3" button if the iframe has a valid soundcloud url as src attribute.

The one thing all valid soundcloud iframes have in common is: all src urls start with

```
//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F
```

Comment: Your code is missing an 'if' statement. You want to check if the `attr` `src` is equal to your `uri` and then return `true` or `false`

Comment: I figured that out aswell.. But could you please elaborate with example code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnbqaz2q/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider the following code snippet:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("buttonId");//get the button
var src = document.getElementById("iframeId").src; // get the src

var url = "//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F"

if(src.indexOf(url) !=-1){ //this will return -1 if false
    btn.style.display = "inline-block";//show the button
}else{
    btn.style.display = "none";//hide the button
}
```

or you can use **regular expression** test function :

```
var btn = document.getElementById("buttonId");//get the button
var src = document.getElementById("iframeId").src; // get the src

var patt = //"/w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F"/;

if(patt.test(src)){ // will return true if found
    btn.style.display = "inline-block";//show the button
}else{
    btn.style.display = "none";//hide the button
}
```

**hope it helps**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the dom element, and check it's `src` attribute.

Something like that:

```js
const src = document.getElementById('ifrm').src;

if (src.indexOf('some')) {
  console.log('YAY');
} else {
  console.log('Not Yay')
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://some-site.com" id="ifrm" />
```